# What happens when calling an async function multiple times

Tags: c#

I have an async function that edits a database in C#

```
public async Task DeleteEntry(int Id)
{
    var toDeleteEntry = (await firebase
      .Child("Entries")
      .OnceAsync<Entry>()).Where(a => a.Object.id == Id).FirstOrDefault();
    await firebase.Child("Entries").Child(toDeleteEntry.Key).DeleteAsync();
}
```

If I call this function in a loop without having a wait function (commented out below)

```
foreach (Entry entry in allData)
{
     var task = DeleteEntry(entry.id);
     //task.Wait();
}
```

Will it:

1. Error out?
2. Create a new thread for each task?
3. Create only 1 thread and block until that thread finishes the next time it iterates the loop?

Please explain.

Comment: 1.no 2.not necessarily 3.no . BTW this has nothing to do with xamarin, and everything to do with c# and firebase. please edit the tags

Comment: If you run it like this, it will run unobserved. Your errors will be swallowed (or thrown from the app domain), and you will have no clue when it all finished. I would suggest `await Task.WhenAll`

Comment: No error will occur when executing the above code. If you want to add await function in the loop, you could just use the following code: `foreach (Entry entry in allData)
{
    await DeleteEntry(entry.id);
}`.

Comment: There is no indication this code will ever create any new thread at all.

Answer (score -1):

Not Throw any Exception. its Work Synchronously First Function Call Then Move To Next Iteration.

if you want to run in Thread Then use

```
public async Task DeleteEntry(int Id)
{ 
    var toDeleteEntry = (await firebase
    .Child("Entries")
    .OnceAsync<Entry>()).Where(a => a.Object.id == Id).FirstOrDefault();
    await firebase.Child("Entries").Child(toDeleteEntry.Key).DeleteAsync();

 }
```

Want To Run With Task Then Use This Code. Its Execute The Method Parallels Thread

```
 var task = Task.Run(() => DeleteEntry(entry.id));
```

Comment: This will not run synchronously. It'll queue one task for each item in the list without waiting for the previous  to complete. Additionally you cannot have a lock statement around an `await`.

Comment: read complete answer first i said its run Synchronously.

Comment: But that's the issue,  it will **not** run synchronously and it will run unobserved. You should consider the feedback you have gotten, the safe approach is to use `Task.WhenAll`. Or if you want it to run in sequence, await after each call.